Prove that $\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} g_k fdm_1 = f(0)$
Suppose that $g$ is a non negative Borel measurable function on $\mathbb{R}$ with $\int_{\mathbb{R}} g dm_1 = 1$ where $m_1$ denotes the one-dimensional Lebesgue measure. For $k \in \mathbb{N}$ set $g_k = k \cdot g(kx)$. Let $f$ be a bounded continuous function. Prove that $$\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} g_k fdm_1 = f(0)$$
Now, explicitly, we have to manipulate
\begin{align}
I_k=\int_{\mathbb{R}} g_k(x) f(x) \, dm_1 = k \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(kx) f(x) \ dm_1
\end{align}
What we know: $f$ is bounded $\implies$ $|f| < M$ for some $M>0$ $\implies f \in L_1(\mathbb{R})$ $($note also that $g \in L_1(\mathbb{R}))$. And $f$ is continuous.
How can we proceed?

Via the change of variables $u=kx$ we find $$k\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(kx) f(x) \ dm_1
=\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(u) f\left(\dfrac{u}{k}\right) \ dm_1
$$
Given that $f$ is bounded by some constant $M$ and $g$ is non negative, we get $$ \left|g(u) f\left(\dfrac{u}{k}\right)\right|\leq Mg(u)$$
As $g$ is integrable, $Mg$ is too.
By the dominated convergence theorem, we may assure that $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(u) f\left(\dfrac{u}{k}\right)\, dm_1=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left[\lim_{k\to\infty} g(u) f\left(\dfrac{u}{k}\right)\right]\, dm_1=\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(u) f(0)\, dm_1=f(0),$$
where we have used that $f$ is continuous and $0$ and that $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(u)\, dm_1=1$.

Thank you for your clear and concise answer. This explains everything perfectly!
